# Is there a way to get logs on how many people download from your yum repository?

Tags: yum

So we host some yum repositories for various customers and I'm wondering if there is any way to find out how often package XYZ gets downloaded from our yum repository? Is this something that is tracked at all? Couldn't find anything via google but maybe someone has experience in this?

Comment: Parsing your web server logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the repo is served by a web server. Web servers keep log files about every file downloaded if you configure them accordingly.

The same is true for repos served by FTP.

Comment: Good point, checked apache logs and it gives some info. access logs is what I checked for others if they are wondering. Thanks!